# Generic Array Index

Tags: c#, arrays, indexing

Does C# have an array type indexable by a generic type (obviously one constrained to `IComparable` or some such)? For example:

```
public class GenericallyIndexedArray<I,T> where I : struct, IComparable { // ...
```

Order is important.

Comment: Are you looking for `IList<T>`?

Comment: @Servy Nope, I'm looking for SortedList. Lee provided the correct answer.

Comment: I can tell you that whatever it is you were planning to use it for, it's almost certainly not the proper data structure for the task.  It's particularly inefficient as data structures go.  It's impossible to say without knowing what your situation is, but there's almost certainly something that's better.

Comment: My situation is described above. Feel free to suggest an alternative. Unless I can use an IComparer<T> as a key, the suggestion is invalid.

Comment: That's not a real situation.  Why do you need the structure to contain comparable objects?  Why does it need to be indexed?  Usually if you need a sorted indexed collection you can just put the items into a regular array or list and sort it occasionally.  If you need a sorted data set that's constantly changing you can usually use a SortedDictionary (which is a tree map) that won't be indexed, but will have much more efficient operations.

Comment: From http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132319.aspx :

The SortedList<TKey, TValue> generic class is an array of key/value pairs with O(log n) retrieval, where n is the number of elements in the dictionary. In this, it is similar to the SortedDictionary<TKey, TValue> generic class. The two classes have similar object models, and both have O(log n) retrieval. Where the two classes differ is in memory use and speed of insertion and removal:

SortedList<TKey, TValue> uses less memory than SortedDictionary<TKey, TValue>.

Comment: SortedDictionary<TKey, TValue> has faster insertion and removal operations for unsorted data, O(log n) as opposed to O(n) for SortedList<TKey, TValue>.

If the list is populated all at once from sorted data, SortedList<TKey, TValue> is faster than SortedDictionary<TKey, TValue>.

Comment: Another difference between the SortedDictionary<TKey, TValue> and SortedList<TKey, TValue> classes is that SortedList<TKey, TValue> supports efficient indexed retrieval of keys and values through the collections returned by the Keys and Values properties. It is not necessary to regenerate the lists when the properties are accessed, because the lists are just wrappers for the internal arrays of keys and values. The following code shows the use of the Values property for indexed retrieval of values from a sorted list of strings:

Comment: Yes, I'm familiar with all of that.  You don't need to quote me an MSDN article on the subject.  That still doesn't indicate, in any way, what actual situation you're in, or even describe any practical problem better solved with `SortedList`.

Comment: A discussion of the details of my "situation" aren't relevant to this conversation. If you'd like to move the conversation elsewhere, feel free to message me. We don't need to clutter up this page with nonsense about ILists.

Comment: There is no private message mechanism on SO.

Comment: "Please avoid extended discussions in comments. Would you like to automatically move this discussion to chat?" <- Sorry, I meant "chat".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's [`SortedList<TKey, TValue>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132319.aspx)

You can supply the `IComparer<T>` to use for the keys, or use the default one if the key type implements it.

Comment: I've yet to ever find a situation in which `SortedList` was the appropriate data structure for the job.